# Format percentage decimal places and remove trailing zeros

Tags: powershell, number-formatting, percentage

Consider the following code:

```
$Obj = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        LimitNew        = 5368709120
        Usage           = 6166915072
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        LimitNew        = 10737418240
        Usage           = 5368709120
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        LimitNew        = 107374182400
        Usage           = 86973087744
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        LimitNew        = 107374182400
        Usage           = 97710505984
    }
)

$CultInfo = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo -ArgumentList 'en-us',$false
$CultInfo.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalDigits = 2
$Obj |select @{L='pct used';E={($_.Usage/$_.LimitNew).ToString('P', $CultInfo)}}
```

It returns the following output:

```
pct used
--------
114.87 %
50.00 % 
81.00 % 
91.00 %
```

What I really would like is the following output:

```
pct used
--------
114.87 %
50 % 
81 % 
91 %
```

When reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-percent-p-format-specifier) I can't seem to find the option to omit trailing zero's when they're there. The method `$CultInfo.NumberFormat.PercentDecimalDigits` specifies to see how many digits after the decimal separator, but not how to omit the zero's.

Comment: _....but why?!_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-3) as well:

> **The "%" Custom Specifier**
>
> A percent sign (`%`) in a format string causes a number to be
>   multiplied by 100 before it is formatted. The localized percent symbol
>   is inserted in the number at the location where the % appears in the
>   format string. The percent character used is defined by the
>   PercentSymbol property of the current NumberFormatInfo object.

The following code snippet should do the trick:

```
$Obj | Select-Object @{
    L='pct used';
    E={($_.Usage/$_.LimitNew).ToString('#0.## %', $CultInfo)}
    }
```

*Result*:

```
pct used
--------
114.87 %
50 %    
81 %    
91 %
```

Comment: I've been searching for this a while now. Your code does exactly what I need. Thank you very much! :)